# Symfony2, how to load data from a controller to fill out a form?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I am not sure if this is entirely possible, but I am mimicking a function from a program built in flat PHP to Symfony2. I am stuck on this one function.

1) Firstly, there is a row of input fields which are dynamically populated.

```
<label for="noofracks"># of racks</label>
        <input type="text" name="noofitems" id="numberform">
<div id="">
<form name="dataform" method="post" action="" id="dataform">
            <input type="hidden" name="lastdasearch">
            <div id="racks">
                <div class="rack" id="rack1">
                    <span id="itemno1"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="open('{{ path('log_searchsub'}}', 'popupwindow', 'width = 600, height = 600, scrollbars = 1'); return false;">Search</a>
    </span>
                    <input type="hidden" id="subid" name="subid1" value="" placeholder="subid" disabled><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="dano" name="dano1" value="" placeholder="dano" disabled><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="partno" name="partno1" value="" placeholder="partno" disabled><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="rackno" name="rackno1" value="" placeholder="rackno" disabled><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="diecode" name="diecode1" value="" placeholder="diecode" disabled><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="heatcode" name="heatcode1" value="" placeholder="heatcode" disabled><br/>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="date" name="shipdate"><br/>
            <input type="number" name="qtyshipped" placeholder="Qty Out"><br/>
            <input type="text" name="blno" placeholder="BL #"><br/>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

2) The input fields under the `<div id="racks">` will populate based on the number that the user inserts into `<input id="numberform"..`. So the next populated row of inputs will have incremented numbers name="dano2", dano3... etc

3) Values are to be inserted from a popup window that lists data from the database and that is where the link `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="open('{{ path('log_searchsub', {'return' : noofitems}) }}', 'popupwindow', 'width = 600, height = 600, scrollbars = 1'); return false;">Search</a>` comes in. It will open a popup with the lists from the database:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <th>DA</th>
                <th>Part</th>
                <th>Batch</th>
                <th>Rack</th>
                <th>Die Code</th>
                <th>Heat Code</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th></th>
            </thead>
            {% for entity in entities %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ entity.dano }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.partno }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.batchno }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.rackno }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.diecode }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.heatcode }}</td>
                <td>{{ entity.inqty }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ path('log_loaddata', {'subid' : entity.subid}) }}">Select</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

4) I have the "Select" link go to the controller that selects that row of data from Doctrine, and I want it to load it into the input fields targeting the right input number (into dano1, partno1, rackno1..). I just.. have NO idea how to go about doing it.

```
/**
 * @Route("/searchsub/{subid}", name="log_loaddata")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function loadDataAction($subid) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('Main');
    $entity = $em->allBySub($subid);

    //get the exact entity that the user selected and load the data into the target input fields. 
    //close the popup window

}
```

If anyone knows a better way to do this, it would be great as well!

EDIT: The desired behavior and action I would like is:

On the contents of each appended `<div class="rack" id="rack1">`, there's a search link that will give a popup window with a table with rows of data listed (the rows list the data of 'dano', 'partno', 'batchno' that is to be inserted into the input fields). Next to each row of data will have a "Select" link, which I want to grab that row of data, and populated to the parent page input fields. I want it to identify which `<div class="rack" id="rack..` to go into (I haven't figured out that part yet either).

Comment: Where is `numberform` that you described? instead of writing the form HTML, consider using the form API by symfony2, it will make your life way easier. Please elaborate about the desired behavior and how the data should be populated from one form to another and I will be happy to help

Comment: @Ramy Oh shoot I meant the `numberform` is in an input field.. not a form. I fixed it in my question and also elaborated my desired function. I hope I made it more clear...

Comment: Does the page need to reload with the new form? or you want the data to be populated using ajax and client-side JS directly?

Comment: @Ramy any way that's best. The original function had it that the data loads into the fields when "Select" was clicked and the popup window closes.

Comment: One last question to be able to help, do you use any JS library ( e.g. jquery, prototype .. etc ) ?

Comment: @Ramy just jquery currently.

Answer (score 0):

So based on what I understood so far what you are trying to do is creating a click function that will get the information from the table row and create input fields with these values. So this will be purely JS stuff.

First you will need to change HTML a little to get stuff to work.

For each input field you want to populate you should replace the `id` field to make it a `data-name` since HTML `id` can not be duplicated and we are going to have multiple fields of these ( aka multiple "racks" )

This:

```
<input type="text" id="dano" name="dano1"  ... />
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" data-name="dano" name="dano1" ... />
```

And the same for the rest of the inputs.

in the HTML for the popup you need to add the same `data-name="[inputName]"` to the `<td>` elements so you can identify them.

for example:

```
<td data-name="dano">{{ entity.dano }}</td>
```

Finally we can add a class to the select link to attach the click event to it:

```
<a class"select-link" data-id="{{ entity.subid }}"  ... >Select</a>
```

Now once you click on the link what you basically need to do is get the information you need to populate. so something like:

```
var parentWindow = window.opener; // get the original window to push info to

$('.select-link').on('click', function(e) {
    var cells = $(this).parent().siblings(); // Get all TD elements in the same row
    var subid = $('this').data('id');

    cells.each(function(i, element){
        var name = $(element).data('name');

        var newRack = parentWindow.$('#rack1').clone() // Clone the row

        // insert data into new rack
        newRack.attr('id', 'rack' + subid);
        $('input[data-name=' + name + ']', newRack)
            .val($(element).text())
            .attr('name', name + subid);
    });

    // Append new rack to the main window
    parentWindow.$('#racks').append(newRack);


});
```

This is just a concept for you to start with of course. It will need some tweaking and googling along the way. Hope it helps.